# Default VM Arguments in Eclipse : -javaagent

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to set the following argument as the Default VM Arguments in Eclipse

```
-javaagent /Developer/aspectj-1.6/aspectjweaver.jar
```

When I add the line and run my code, it gives me the error:

```
Unrecognized option: -javaagent
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: -javaagent:D:\log4jproject\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar (location of the aspectjweaver jar  location )  in vm arguments.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need a colon (`:`) between the `-javaagent` and the JAR, not a space.  For example:

```
-javaagent:/Developer/aspectj-1.6/aspectjweaver.jar
```

Comment: Also, just want to add that it cannot be an `=` either, like we use for other arguments. Looks like it has to be only the colon, `:`

Comment: Also, do not forget to include double quotes around the path if the path has spaces.
   `-javaagent:"/Developer/aspectj 1.6/aspectjweaver.jar"`